# For таймер при повторение кода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно как то добавить 5 секунд тайминг прежде чем опять повторять код

```
function drawFriends(friends) {
for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) { // Дальше код должен выполняться каждных 5 секунд
    var f = friends[i];
sendRequest('messages.send', {user_id: f.id, message: 'test', random_id: getRandomInt(10000000)}, function(data) {
console.log(data)
        
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout должен вам помочь

```js
let friends = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]
function drawFriends(friends) {
  let t = -5000
  for (let elem of friends) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      //здесь вставляете то, что нужно выполнить
      console.log(elem.id) //для примера
    },t+=5000)
  }
}   
drawFriends(friends)
```